# QR version setting in Zxing [Android]?

Tags: android, image, qr-code, zxing

**I would like to generate QR image with the following setting:**

1. Specific version number, i.e: v04.
2. Correction Level: L. (which can be done)
3. BarcodeFormat: QRCode. (which can be done)
4. EncodingMode: Byte mode.

P/S, QR content: Base64-encoded String.

---

**Question:**

How could I define the QR code version number? I saw `EncodeHintType`, but yields no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the version. "Version" is just size. Size needs to be big enough to hold the data. Making it bigger just makes it harder to scan.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I was trying to regenerate the scanned QR images, which is initially generated using C# lib, v4. The re-generated Zxing QR and C# QR image pattern doesn't matched.

Comment: So how about the QR encoding? Can it be set to binary?

Comment: The encoding depends on more than version, and EC level. It depends on the masking pattern chosen, and the underlying data encoding. Even when you choose byte mode (is that what you mean by binary) for text encoding, the result depends on the character encoding you choose. And ECI segments you may add, and how you choose to chop the text into multiple segments. What is your actual requirement?

Comment: My requirement: ECC level: L, EncodingMode: Binary, Version: 4. which means the capacity can store up to 78 bytes. http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html#versionPage1_10. Look into the version list 1-10. But due to I cant set the version number in Zxing, therefore the generated QR Image using Zxing doesn't not look the same as QR image generated by other library.

Comment: Since the version cant be set, Can I set the QR encodingmode to binary instead? Is the option named CHARACTER_SET? And I'm using Base64-String to be the QR content.

Comment: You can set a non-standard character encoding, yes. But there is no point to that if the content is already Base64 encoded, since it works within the ISO-8859-1 encoding. Base64 will require byte mode (there is no such thing as "binary mode") in any event, already. Surely your requirement is "up to version 4". It is already going to generate the correct and optimal code.

Comment: ALright, "BYTE" :) I have found this generator able to generate exactly the same QR image. http://www.racoindustries.com/barcodegenerator/2d/qr-code.aspx .But Zxing can't get the same image.

Comment: Let the content be: j/WXqr9HaRTw7kbtG6/npfDuRu0br+el+PCCM+o/7eJCP4W8H3lItA==

Comment: although the QR pattern are not the same, the content of both QR images is actually same after scanned.

Comment: Of course. There are many valid encodings of the same info, and none are "correct" though some are more optimal than others. Here zxing is probably choosing a different masking pattern. Or if you have asked for a different encoding, adding an ECI segment.

Comment: Okay, I got your point now, btw how do I add an ECI segment? do you mind to provide me an example? :)

Comment: Actually the library i used for another QR image generator is messagingtoolkit.qrcode, have you heard of it?

Comment: You should not need to specify an encoding or add an ECI segment. You said you had tried it and I'm just saying it would be another reason for difference. Don't set it. No I have not heard of that library.